# Why Spring Framework doesn´t find my jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am trying to understand how Spring Framework process a JSP manually without Spring Boot and current example is not working.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        startTomcat();
    }

    static void startTomcat() throws Exception {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.getConnector().setPort(8080);
        Context context = tomcat.addContext("", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(SpringConfig.class);
        appContext.refresh();

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(appContext);
        Wrapper wrapper = context.createWrapper();
        wrapper.setName("dispatcherServlet");
        wrapper.setServlet(dispatcherServlet);
        context.addChild(wrapper);
        wrapper.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        wrapper.addMapping("/");

        try {
            tomcat.start();
            tomcat.getServer().await();
        } catch (LifecycleException e) {
            System.out.println("Katakroker");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    class SpringConfig {

        @Bean
        static StaticWebApplicationContext applicationContext() {
            System.out.println("Adding a StaticWebApplicationContext");
            StaticWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new StaticWebApplicationContext();
            // Add JSP View Resolver
            applicationContext.registerBean(ViewResolver.class, () -> {
                InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
                viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
                viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/"); // Path to JSP files
                viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
                return viewResolver;
            });
            return applicationContext;
        }

        @Bean
        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes() {
            System.out.println("Adding a route");
            return RouterFunctions.route()
                    .GET("/hello2", request -> ServerResponse.ok().render("hello")) // Handle JSP rendering
                    .build();
        }

        @PostConstruct
        private void postConstruct() {
            System.out.println("Running Spring Config");
        }
    }

}
```

When I execute the code, Tomcat is working fine, but current configuration does´t see the jsp file. What is missing in current configuration?

```
curl http://localhost:8080/hello2

Running Spring Config
Adding a StaticWebApplicationContext
Adding a route
Aug 28, 2023 4:39:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 28, 2023 4:39:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Aug 28, 2023 4:39:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
Aug 28, 2023 4:39:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
16:39:44.395 [info.jab.ms.jsp.Main.main()] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -- Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
16:39:44.669 [info.jab.ms.jsp.Main.main()] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -- Completed initialization in 269 ms
Aug 28, 2023 4:39:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16:40:11.225 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound -- No mapping for GET /hello
```

Source code: https://github.com/jabrena/servlet-archaeology/blob/feature/jsp/2-spring-framework/src/main/java/info/jab/ms/jsp/Main.java

Many thanks in advance

Comment: And it should because? The routes are totally ignored, that should be a bean not some static function. Your prefix is wrong as well it should be `/WEB-INF/` currently (if it worked) it will try to render the `WEB-INF/hello.jsp.hello.jsp`.

Comment: I updated the method: `viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");` if you observe I pass that method to ServletDispatcher: `Context context = tomcat.addContext("", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
  DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext(routes()));
  Tomcat.addServlet(context, "dispatcherServlet", dispatcherServlet).addMapping("/");` But it is not working.

Comment: NIce that you are passing it, but that is useless as it isn't added as a bean to the context. Hence it is useless as I stated before.

Comment: I updated it, take a look the original code ^^

Comment: I have the impression that the RouterFunction is not working with this configuration. But the bean is registered.

Comment: Registering it as `static` is useless, also now your view resolver will not be registered as it is embedded in an applicationcontext in an application context. Just create a regular `@Configuration` iwth 2 beans 1 for the routerfunction one for the view resolver. Why all the complexity. You will also need `@EnableWebMvc` for all the request mapping hanlders to be registered.

Comment: Why all the complexity? I am trying to understand few details about how Spring Boot do the stuff easily. :) Can you provide an example for this part? `You will also need @EnableWebMvc for all the request mapping hanlders to be registered.`?

Comment: If you want to understand Spring Boot I would strongly suggest to read the Spring documentation (which is a step I feel you have skipped and you just start throwing things together and when things don't work ask questions here). You need to enable Spring MVC by adding `@EnableWebMvc` to the `@Configuration` class.

Comment: I added the annotation, but I received the following message: `An exception occured while executing the Java class. Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: No ServletContext set` I belive that it is something new

Comment: Yes, i read that documentation several times :p

Comment: From what you are showing here, that doesn't really show (sorry for the bluntness). You are calling refresh on the context you are creating, don't.